# No undestanding the different API Levels in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently creating an Android application with Eclipse and in the build sdk for API Level 8 it has

Android 2.2 (API 8)
Google APIs (Google Inc) (API 8)
DTS Add-ON (KYOCERA Corporation)(API 8)
Real3d Add-on (LGE)(API 8)

They all have api 8. So if I were to choose Real3d Add-on (LGE) (API 8) does that mean it would have all the previous functionality of (API-8) for instance DTS Add-ON (KYOCERA Corporation)(API 8) is a subset and Google APIs (Google Inc) (API 8) is a subset of DTS Add-ON (KYOCERA Corporation)(API 8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are starting to learn android.  Use Android 2.2 (API 8) to build your app.  DTS Addon, Real3D and other manufacturer add-ons are specific to few devices only

Answer (score 0):

API levels are the minimum required to be able to use it.

As android progressed, new features came out and these were introduced in theh new api levels.

Any api device equal and above can run that API feature.

E.g. an API 10 phone can run API 1-10 features.

An API phone 8 can run API 1-8 features. Aka cannot run API 10 features.

If you need a feature from a certain API, just note, that no devices below the desired API will be able to run your app. API 8 is a good target API.

Comment: So Real3d Add-on (LGE) (API 8) has just has more features than DTS Add-ON (KYOCERA Corporation)(API 8) ?

Comment: @stack No, they both use the same android API. And are dependant on API-8 minimum. So will only run on phones that are API 8 and above.